# maximum of sequence of nonnegative random variables which converge in distribution to $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, weak-convergence

Let {$x_i$} be a sequence of nonnegative random variables. Assume there exist positive numbers $\mu$ and $\sigma$, such that $$\frac {1}{\sigma\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)\Rightarrow N(0,1).$$

Is it true that $\max_{i\leq n}x_i/\sqrt n$ converges to $0$ in probability?

What if we further assume that {$x_i$} are iid with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's true, at least for the latter case that $\left\{X_{i}\right\}$ are i.i.d. with finite variance.

By Fubini's theorem we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}^{2}\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}2x\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}\geq x\right)dx,$$
hence the existence of variance implies that the tail $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}\geq x\right)$ decays faster than $x^{-2}$ for sufficiently large $x$,
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}\geq x\right)\lesssim x^{-2}.$$
For the limiting tail, say random variable $Y_{i}$ with $\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{i}\geq y\right)\asymp y^{-2}$, we have
$$Kn^{-1/2}\max_{1\leq i\leq n}Y_{i}\overset{\mathcal{L}}{\to}\xi,$$
where $\xi$ follows a Fréchet distribution $\mathbb{P}\left(\xi\leq t\right)=\exp\left(-t^{-2}\right)$, which implies $\max_{1\leq i\leq n}Y_{i}=O_{p}\left(n^{1/2}\right)$. Since $X_{i}$ have a "strictly lighter tail" than $Y_{i}$, the maximum should have a order smaller than root $n$, thus
$$n^{-1/2}\max_{1\leq i\leq n}X_{i}\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\to}0.$$

For the case that $\left\{X_{i}\right\}$ are not i.i.d., a CLT holds for partial sum also put some restrictions on the tail, the similar idea may work but the discussion will be more complicated.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain or give a reference about the converging to a Frechet distribution part?

Comment: @allen i: Maybe this here is helpful: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem

Comment: @alleni The derivation is not hard, simply take limit of $F^{n}\left(x\right)$. For detailed proof and reference, you can find it in chapter 3 of "Modeling Extremal Events for Insurance and Finance" by P. Embrechts, C. Kluppelberg, T. Mikosch.